# Django enumaration problem

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, enumeration

I try to implement enumartion structure in django such that

```
class Status():
PENDING = 0
CONFIRMED = 1
DENIED = 2

STATUS =(
    (PENDING,_("salary_status_pending")),
    (CONFIRMED,_("salary_status_confirmed")),
    (DENIED,_("salary_status_denied")),
)
```

and in my model I use it like

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    status = models.IntegerField(null=False, choices=Status.STATUS)
```

It works fine and if I want to get the label of enum field in my template I use
`{{ mymodel.get_status_display }}` and it writes the label `_('key..')` in my enum field instead of number which is explained in Django documents

However, what if I want to get the label in my `view.py` ?
I want to write a code below and it should give me the label of enum field instead of number

```
Status.CONFIRMED
```

How can I achive this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it.The code below does what I want

```
Status.STATUS [Status.CONFIRMED ][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    PENDING = 0
    CONFIRMED = 1
    DENIED = 2

    STATUS = {PENDING:_("salary_status_pending"), CONFIRMED:..., DENIED:... }    
    STATUS_CHOICES = [(a,a) for a in STATUS.items()]    
    status = models.IntegerField(null=False, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
```

And you can access your label everywhere using `MyModel.STATUS[MyModel.CONFIRMED]`

Comment: it is definetly a good solution thank you ! But I have almost ave 20 enum fields any modifying them like that may result in severe.. Is there any other solution without changing the enum class ?

Comment: You can construct dict on the fly: `dict(Status.STATUS)[Status.CONFIRMED]`